# Can't start debugserver on iPhone device Xcode 7.1 error

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, device

When I run the iOS device, Xcode is giving me a error...

**Could not start debug server on "iPhone" when trying to launch "Monster"**

This never happened before, why is this happening now? What is this? What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

I have been seeing this issue now with Xcode 9.

What fixes it for me is restarting the device.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

A good ole quit Xcode and unplug my iPhone worked for me. Restarted, reconnected and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9:-

Just restarting the Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this can happen if your app has not been verified.

Settings -> General -> Device Management -> [Your developer ID here] -> Verify App

[Restart Xcode]

Should fix the problem